# why anova() function is not applicable for models build using ridge regression and lasso regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, anova

```
linRidgeMod <- linearRidge(Class ~ ., data = training[,vars])
anova(linRidgeMod)
```

or

```
mod <- lmridge(Class ~ ., data = training[,vars],K = 0.012)
anova(mod)
```

or

```
ridge_reg <- glmnet(x_train, y_train, nlambda = 25, alpha = 0, family = 'gaussian', lambda = lambdas)
anova(ridge_reg)
```

I have tried all the three methods to train model using ridge regression. The same common error is displayed for all these methods which is shown below.

```
Error in UseMethod("anova") : 
  no applicable method for 'anova' applied to an object of class "ridgeLinear".

Error in UseMethod("anova") : 
  no applicable method for 'anova' applied to an object of class "glmnet".
```

Answer (score 1):

Same reason why LASSO or RIDGE do not return standard errors or test statistics or p-values. It does not make sense to do so because the models introduce bias in the coefficients by design (to improve predictions), which makes any tests on mean values  of coefficients inappropriate.